# jQuery: Removing/Adding Classes from links within li's?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to create tabs, which works fine by adding a class="current" to the li - which changes the background of the current tab...great...

I now need to use this code to instead add the class="current" to the  "a" tag within the li - instead of the li....it can add it fine, but, the trouble is it now doesn't remove it from the other li "a" that was highlighted... for example:

```
 jQuery(this).closest("li a").addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
```

Html

```
<li id="slide_brand"><a class="current" href="#tab1">Brands</a></li>
<li id="slide_sites"><a href="#tab2">Sites</a></li>
<li id="slide_photo"><a href="#tab3">Photos</a></li>
```

Must be to do with the "siblings" part... but I don't know what to change it too! :(

Can someone help please?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post a short sample of your markup?

Comment: I think we're missing some information. How do you know which page is "current", is there a body class?

Comment: I've added my html - the class="current" is on the starting a tag. - Then if you click another, it removes it from the starting tag and adds it to the one you just clicked - well it should do! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better approach in doing this is still adding the class at the `li` level.

try this instead:

```
li.select > a
{
    background: red;
}

li > a
{
    display: block;
}
```

for javascript part:

```
$("#menu > li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
})
```

Comment: I know the li level, if you saw intro post, but have to add it to the "a" part this time around. Thanks anyway.

Comment: if you insist with your approach, I bet something like this would help: `jQuery(this).closest("li a").addClass("current").parent().siblings().children("a").removeClass("current");`

Comment: @You that removes the class you just added

Comment: No sorry, that broke the tabs script entriely, thanks though.

Comment: @CodeyMonkey what is really the `$(this)` object? I was always assume it as `"li > a"`.

@ori could it be the `closest("li a")`? else, `parent().siblings()` will be excluding the a.current's parent. I dont see how the newly assigned .current will get removed.

Comment: It can easily be done to li's - but why not "a" tags within them?

Comment: Yes!! You got it! - thanks very much for spending time with me on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var el = jQuery(this);

el.closest("ul").find(".current").removeClass("current");
el.closest("li a").addClass("current")

This will remove the current class, then re-add it to the relevant item...

Comment: Hi, - It just adds an empty class="" instead of class="current"... any ideas please?

Comment: lol, sorry, the last bit of that chain will remove the class it just added, I've edited it